# Invoke operation error

Tags: php

I have the following function in the php script,

```
public function createPorductstatushistory($item) {

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "INSERT INTO $this->tablename (timeStamp, ProductDetail_idProduct, ProductStatus_idStatus) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param
    ($stmt, 'sii', 
    $item->timeStamp->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 
    $item->ProductDetail_idProduct, 
    $item->ProductStatus_idStatus);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $autoid = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
    mysqli_close($this->connection);

    return $autoid;
}
```

but, everytime I go to the part "$item->timeStamp->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')". The following error pop up.

> There was an error while invoking the operation. Check your operation
>   inputs or server code and try invoking the operation again.
>
> Reason:  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fypweee_admin\FYPadminSideV3-debug\services\PorductstatushistoryService.php
>   on line 125
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function toString() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fypweee_admin\FYPadminSideV3-debug\services\PorductstatushistoryService.php
>   on line 125

Is this mean the  `timeStamp` var need to be in format of 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'?

Comment: Your $item parameter most likely doesn't have a timestamp property defined on it. If I were to get this error, the first thing I would do is debug to that line and verify first that the $item is initialized, and that it had a timestamp property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$item` object has a property `timeStamp`. You assume that the `timeStamp` property of `$item` is an object. But the error tells you that `timeStamp` is not an object.

This could mean that you never set an instance of an object to `timeStamp`.

Example:

```
class TimeStamp
{
    time = '13:00';
}

class Item
{
    public $timeStamp;
}

$item = new Item();
$item->timeStamp->time;
```

This would result in such an error. You need to initialize `TimeStamp` and assign that to your `$timeStamp` variable.

```
class TimeStamp
{
    time = '13:00';
}

class Item
{
    public $timeStamp;

    public Item()
    {
        $this->$timeStamp = new TimeStamp();
    }
}

$item = new Item();
$item->timeStamp->time;
```

Now this should work, because `TimeStamp` is initialized in the constructor and assigned to the `$timeStamp` variable.

So please recheck your code and make sure everything you need is instantiated